# Why doesn't this group by work how I want or expect it to

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am trying to make this query return count by a group. But it doesn't group data.

```
  notification = AppointmentNotificationGroupAppointment.objects.filter(receiver__notification_group__group=group).values('receiver__notification_group__group', 'sender__status__name').annotate(pcount=Count('sender__status__name', distinct=True))
```

It returns:

```
{'receiver__notification_group__group': '841536_123856', 'sender__status__name': 'Pending', 'pcount': 1},
{'receiver__notification_group__group': '841536_123856', 'sender__status__name': 'Pending', 'pcount': 1},
{'receiver__notification_group__group': '841536_123856', 'sender__status__name': 'Confirmed', 'pcount': 1}, 
{'receiver__notification_group__group': '841536_123856', 'sender__status__name': 'Confirmed', 'pcount': 1}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want it to return distinct records with them counted by group

Comment: Try **`AppointmentNotificationGroupAppointment.objects.filter(receiver__notification_group__group=group).values('receiver__notification_group__group', 'sender__status__name').annotate(pcount=Count('sender__status__name', distinct=True)).order_by('receiver__notification_group__group')`**

Comment: Works!

You can post this as answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've added the same as Answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the **`order_by(...)`** too

```
AppointmentNotificationGroupAppointment.objects.filter(receiver__notification_group__group=group).values(
    'receiver__notification_group__group',
    'sender__status__name').annotate(pcount=Count('sender__status__name', distinct=True)
                                     ).order_by('receiver__notification_group__group')
```